# Unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION fix

Tags: php, oop

I am getting this syntax error when running my php. Here is the code for a class I am trying to costruct:

```
function makeObject($s) {
    $secobj = new mySimpleClass($s);
    return $secobj;
}

class mySimpleClass {

    $secret = ""; 

    public function __construct($s) {
        $this -> secret = $s;
    }

    public function getSecret() {
        return base64_encode(string $secret);
    }
}
```

Anyone see whats wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the visibility of `$secret`

```
private $secret = "";
```

Then just remove that casting on the base64 and use `$this->secret` to access the property:

```
return base64_encode($this->secret);
```

So finally:

```
class mySimpleClass 
{

    // public $secret = "";
    private $secret = '';

    public function __construct($s) 
    {
        $this->secret = $s;
    }

    public function getSecret() 
    {
        return base64_encode($this->secret);
    }
}
```

Comment: so it is supposed to echo                                          mySimpleClass Object
(
    [secret:mySimpleClass:private] => Honey Pot
)                                                         sg9uzxkgug90                                                  but it only echos                                         mySimpleClass Object
(
    [secret] => Honey Pot
)

Comment: @Felicia you need to echo it from your getter method. `echo $obj->getSecret()`

Comment: oh I forgot to mention this is connected to another php file which contains                                                                   <?php 
            $obj = makeObject("Honey Pot");
            print_r($obj); 
            echo $obj->getSecret();
          ?>

Comment: @Felicia just use the getter function that you have. here is the demo so that you can see http://codepad.viper-7.com/wKthLW

Comment: Aye good, no need for the $secret to be public at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to declare `$secret` as `public` or `private` & access it using `$this->`. Example:

```
class mySimpleClass {
    public $secret = "";
    public function __construct($s) {
        $this -> secret = $s;
    }
    public function getSecret() {
        return base64_encode($this->$secret);
    }
}
```